# Deprecation warning: ReactDOM.render is no longer supported in React 18

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-redux, react-hooks, react-router

Why is react.js v.18 giving this warning?

> ReactDOM.render is no longer supported in React 18. Use createRoot instead. Until you switch to the new API, your app will behave as if it's running React 17.

How can I migrate my app to use `createRoot` instead?